# Why does 2D crystalline lattice of Graphene overlap with its reciprocal lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, graphene, x-ray-crystallography

Can someone please explain why the 2D electron-diffraction pattern of graphene coincidentally overlaps with its reciprocal lattice? I want to understand/know the reason behind this coincidence in the case of Graphene which is an example of a perfect 2D crystal.

Comment: Since the reciprocal lattice of a hexagonal real space lattice is itself a hexagonal lattice (although rotated relative to each other), one would expect the diffraction pattern to be hexagonal based on the reciprocal lattice. It is not a coincidence.

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Would your response still remain the same?

Comment: The diffraction pattern should be a direct representation of the reciprocal lattice - the diffraction is caused by the lattice momentum from the reciprocal lattice.

Comment: Do the 2 possibilities for incident ray (moving up or down; only angle alpha could be changed in the dot product of the vectors incident ray and the reciprocal lattice G) in 2D crystal structures also have anything to do with this behavior?